# 160 characters limit for SMS messages

Tags: java

I have one field which can contain from 1 to unlimited number of characters. I want to restrict to send maximum 3 messages (so minimum 1 maximum 3). So it is maximum 480 characters. I want to list (write in output) each message separately (from 0-160; 160-320; 320-480).All over the 480 is not my concern.

My class  works when there are on example 500 characters but for small number of characters like in example it wont work.

```
 String message="message to sent";
 int m=message.length();


b=160;
int c=m/b;


int bi=0;
int ei=160;



for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
    while (ei<=480)
    {
    System.out.println("\n"+message.substring(bi, ei));
    bi=bi+160;
    ei=ei+160;
    }
}
```

what do I have to correct to work this completely and for small number of characters in message and for large messages?
    thank you

Comment: Nice job. Let the Internet do your Homework! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int c=m/b;
```

`c` will be rounded down while casted to `int` so it will be the `number of sms - 1` if `m < b`, you should write :

```
int c = (int) Math.ceil((double) m/b);
```

Or, since `m` and `b` are positives :

```
int c = (m+b-1)/b;
```

Besides, i don't understand the purpose of your double loop, if you want to display each message block you can loop over `c` :

```
for(int i = 0; i < c && i < 3; i++) {
    int start = i*b;
    int end = Math.min( (i+1)*b, m);
    System.out.println( message.substring(start, end) );
}
```

Or you can loop over an `offset` :

```
for(int offset = 0; offset<b*c && offset<b*3; offset+=b) {
    System.out.println( message.substring(offset , Math.min(m, offset+b) ) );
}
```

But you can't do both.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained *why* it works.

Comment: `substring` method will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` within a `while` loop. Your fix is not sufficient.

Comment: @PM77-1 Are you suggesting `start` and `end` can be out of the string bounds ?

Comment: yes start and end are out of the string bouds that is exception I was getting

Comment: @zakinster - As you can see from time stamps, I posted my comment 2 minutes **before** you updated your answer.  Now this particular aspect seems to be fine.  I'm not sure about your `message.length() - 1` part though.   Have you tried to test it with a string of  (let say) 2  characters?

Comment: @zakinster - 
From the Java specs for **substring**: The substring begins at the specified `beginIndex` and extends to the character at index `endIndex - 1`.  So, `"12".substring(0, 2)` will return `"12"`. Following your code, in case of `2-character string`, your `end'` will be `1`. You will call `message.substring(0,1)` and return just the 1st character.

Comment: @PM77-1 Just checked the doc and the second index is actually exclusive, so it should be message.length() (as my initial revision). Where did you get an exception ?

Comment: @zakinster - Just get rid of `-1` and let's consider the issue closed.

Comment: @zakinster I am still getting  String index out of range: -

Comment: @PM77-1 There wans't the `-1` in the first place, I added it after your comment.

Comment: for the offset I think I am getting correct result. you just need to add one more ")" in system out println

Comment: @jajaaaa for the second version indeed.

Comment: I also have error to cast c to int. I did that..is that correct?

Comment: @jajaaaa actually it should be `(double) Math.ceil((double)m/b)` otherwise that would be the same as `m/b`.

Comment: int c = (double) Math.ceil((double) m/b);  don;t you have to change ant type of c to double? sorry I am confused...have you maybe test it to check if it works completely?

Comment: I think now is totally correct. you just need to chnage tyep to double.Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @jajaaaa note that I added another option to avoid doing a double division and using ceil.

Comment: ok because with double I think it is not correct expression. But thank you very much. You solved it!

Comment: @jajaaaa Sorry I corrected a bit too quickly, it should be `(int) Math.ceil((double) m/b)`which is perfectly correct or `(m+b-1)/b` which in this case gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You need `message.substring(bi, ei < m ? ie : m));` for the case when `m` isn't a multiple of 160

Also, exit the `for` loop when you reach the end of the message

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a lot wrong with this code.

1. As zakinster already answered: `m/b` rounds down to `0` if `m < b`, so your for loop is never executed
2. Your double loop is unnecessary and will lead to trouble as soon as you solve problem 1.
3. You don't test for the end of the message

You would do better to replace the last double loop by:

```
int offset = 0;
int length;

while (offset < 480 && offset < m) {
    length = Math.min(160, m - offset);
    System.out.println("\n"+message.substring(offset, offset+length));
    offset += 160;
}
```

Comment: strange...your code works for small message but it writes in one line longer message...although there are "\n" it writes it in same line